# "Error in seq_len(p) " when using predict in R

Tags: r, predict

I'm using the OME data from the MASS package and I'm using the gee package to fit the model.

```
model <- gee(cbind(Correct, Trials-Correct)~Loud+Age+OME+Noise, id=ID,
data=OME, family=binomial, corstr="exchangeable")
```

I'm trying to use predict but get an error

```
predict(model,newdata=OME[1,])
```

> ```
>     Error in seq_len(p) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
>     In addition: Warning messages:
>     1: In predict.lm(object, newdata, se.fit, scale = 1, type = ifelse(type ==  :
>     calling predict.lm(<fake-lm-object>) ...
>     2: In seq_len(p) : first element used of 'length.out' argument
> ```

I know for my example I could just do `predict(model)[1]` I just want to know for the general case.
Thanks!